# How to keep JS objects with references between Angular app launches?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, object

I need to serialize the state in an Angular app and load it next time the app is launched.

**The problem is**:

The state contains objects referencing other objects that should be saved, but if I try to serialize it with `JSON.stringify()` I get cyclic object reference error here and there. 
Eventually I should also have a way to share the app state with other users, for example by url link.

How do i solve these problems and how to serialize reference without losing data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have cyclic references in the first place?

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to find where those cyclic object references are and remove them.

Comment: Maybe you should use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only approach I can think of, aside maybe using IndexedDB is very verbose. There might be better solutions, but this is what I would think:

**Persisting State**

1. Flatten your object structure, with reference ids. Like in the [HATEOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) or [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/).

A very basic example would be:

*Original Object structure*

```
{
    name: "John",
    kids: [
        { name: "mike" },
        { name: "tracy" }
    ]
}
```

*flattened*

```
{
    persons: [
        { id: 1, name: "John", kids: [2,3], parent: null },
        { id: 2, name: "mike", kids: [], parent: 1 },
        { id: 3, name: "tracy", kids: [], parent: 1}
    ]
}
```

Now there is no cyclic referneces

2. Stringify and persist the flattened version.

**Fetching State**

1. Read the peristed data and do `JSON.parse()`
2. Recreate the original Object structure

There might be tools out there to help you with this. Tools that try to comply with HATEOS or JSON:API.

**Not ideal, but it would work, but comes with a lot of boilerplate and maintenance**

Comment: I was thinking of adding Redux Store to my project and it feels like it could make flattening state easier. Your aproach is good, but maybe there is better solution :)

Comment: @SergPiert that sounds like a better approach! If you can find a better tool/library that automates this, I strongly suggest to use so. 

Comment: @SergPiert tools like [this](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) (just an example) might help you out.

Comment: Yes, that's thing i was looking for. At least it solves state persistence problems, thanks 